# Get Metadata Last Modified by into GIT without check in/out

Tags: developer, git, continuous-integration, developer-productivity

I am passively pulling out the metadata periodically and pushing it into GIT. No issues there. This is not full blown CI, more to ensure we have source control around all our metadata.

Is it possible to get the LastModified user into this process somehow?

Eventually Developers will be checking in/out but that's some way off.

Any ideas / pointers?

Comment: Clarification. I am talking about the LastModified which you can see when you view classes through the Salesforce UI as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can access this from the metadata via the tooling REST API using the following query URL:

```
/services/data/v32.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT FullName, lastModifiedById FROM ApexClass
```

This will give you the raw data, which you can use in your process.

If you want to explore your Apex class data in the Workbench you can at the following URL: https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=ApexClass

Comment: That's useful. I could grab the current list like this and commit this along with the metadata which I have pulled using ANT.  Is that the best I am going to get without each developer checking in the code they change?

Comment: My current client has each developer commit their own individual changes into Git, which is the nicest solution because you can also attribute each commit to a story.
This data could be used to either append the commit comment, or as you say stored in Git itself as content.

Comment: We will definitely evolve into that flow

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the download yourself using the SOAP Metadata API, then you can access the [RetrieveResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieveresult.htm) and get the [FileProperties](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieveresult.htm#retrieveresult_fileproperties) that have the date and last changed by.

This is what we use in [Gearset to work out who changed what and when](https://gearset.com/blog/who-changed-what-and-when)